# How to make generated via Google Apps Script comments visible as human-written?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, comments, google-docs

I want to generate comments using Add-ons in Google Docs, but they differ from human-written. They are displayed in comments threads (by clicking on comment sign in head menu), but they do not appear on the right-hand side of the document (like usual comments do). Can it be fixed?

I've found "kix"-anchors - this is the only thing that I find different between these types.

Can I get kix from Google or generate it somehow?

Comment: AFAIK, Not possible

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs API doesn't implements any way to insert any type of comments inside a document. The only type of comments you can insert in any Google Document (Docs, Spreadsheet, etc) are the ones you have in the comment history menu (which is in the top and right of any document), you can insert these type of comments with the Advanced Drive Service functions [1] and using the information to create comments from Google Docs API [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive

[2] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/create